# How can I get the state of child checkbox components within a parent ListView component using React-Native?

Tags: listview, react-native, components, parent-child, state

I have a list of options with check boxes and a done button inside a parent `ListView`. When the done button is pressed, I want to know which of the check boxes are checked.

I should add that I have tried to maintain an array of the checked boxes in the `ListView` using callback functions from `ChildCheckBox`.  It worked fine except when navigating back to the `ListView`, the array would be reset while the check boxes still appeared to be checked. I would prefer to have the `onDonePress()` function just query which boxes are checked then respond accordingly at that time rather than rely on the `ListView` maintaining a an array.

Here is the `ListView`:

```
class ParentListView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(ROW_DATA),
    });
  }

  onCheckPress() {
    console.log('Check Pressed')
    // callback from ChildCheckBoxCell...?
  }

  onDonePress() {
    console.log('Done pressed')
    // callback from ChildDoneCell...?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        style={styles.listView}
        />
    );
  }

  renderRow(cell) {
    if (cell.type === 'ChildCheckBoxCell') {
      return (
        <ChildCheckBoxCell onChange={() => this.onCheckPress()} />
      );
    }

    if (cell.type === 'ChildDoneCell') {
      return (
        <ChildDoneCell onDonePress={() => this.onDonePress()}/>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the `ChildCheckBoxCell` component:

```
class ChildCheckBoxCell extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isChecked: false,
    };
  }

  onChange() {
    this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
    //Callback...
    this.props.onChange();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onChange()}>
        <Text>{this.state.isChecked? 'Checked' : 'UnChecked'}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

And finally, here is the `ChildDoneCell` component

```
class ChildDoneCell extends Component {

  onDonePress() {
    //Callback...
    this.props.onDonePress();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onDonePress()}>
        <Text>DONE</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you should do. I included comments in the code to explain. There should be 6 steps.

```
class ParentListView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(ROW_DATA),
    });
  }

  // 1. Change your callback functions to class properties
  // this way it is auto-bound to this class instance and you don't bind it during render, which
  // creates rendering overhead. Notice how the selected `cell` is
  // passed in here. It will be explained in the last steps how that happens.
  onCheckPress = (cell) => {
    // Update the `isChecked` state of this cell and update
    // your `ListView.DataSource` with it
    console.log('Check Pressed', cell);
    // callback from ChildCheckBoxCell...?
  };

  // 2. Do the same thing here as step 1.
  onDonePress = (cell) => {
    console.log('Done pressed', cell);
    // callback from ChildDoneCell...?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        style={styles.listView}
        />
    );
  }

  renderRow(cell) {
    if (cell.type === 'ChildCheckBoxCell') {
      return (
        // 3. You should pass in the cell data down here AND you should
        // pass a reference to your callback
        <ChildCheckBoxCell cell={cell} onChange={this.onCheckPress} />
      );
    }

    if (cell.type === 'ChildDoneCell') {
      // 4. Do the same thing here, except change the reference of 
      // the callback to the other callback, obviously
      return (
        <ChildDoneCell cell={cell} onDonePress={this.onDonePress}/>
      );
    }
  }
}

class ChildCheckBoxCell extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      // 5. Dereference the function `onChange` and bind it to your
      // `cell` object, don't worry about `null` changing your 
      // `this` context, it won't. This is how the `cell` object is
      // passed an argument in the method on step 1.
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onChange.bind(null, this.props.cell)}>
        {/* Stop using `state` to keep track of `isChecked`, you'll
            lose this state if this ever is torn down and re-rendered
            from the parent component */}
        <Text>{this.props.cell.isChecked? 'Checked' : 'UnChecked'}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

class ChildDoneCell extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      // 6. This is the same thing as step 5.
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onDonePress.bind(null, this.props.cell)}>
        <Text>DONE</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

You will notice that you could bind the `cell` data in the `renderRow` function, but it is not preferred. The rule of thumb to follow is that you want to dereference your callback function to your child data as far down as possible for performance reasons, and because it is better to be explicit for maintenance reasons. This is the shortcut alternative:

```
// ParentListView
renderRow(cell) {
  if (cell.type === 'ChildCheckBoxCell') {
    return (
      // No more passing of cell, but now I'm binding it with the
      // cell object
      <ChildCheckBoxCell onChange={this.props.onCheckPress.bind(null, cell)} />
    );
  }

  if (cell.type === 'ChildDoneCell') {
    // Same thing
    return (
      <ChildDoneCell onDonePress={this.onDonePress.bind(null, cell)}/>
    );
  }
}

// ChildCheckBoxCell

render() {
  return (
    // Notice how you lose the explicitness of your callback
    // function and have no idea that this function implicitly passes
    // the `cell` object because you prematurely bound it with the `cell` object
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onChange}>
      <Text>{this.props.isChecked? 'Checked' : 'UnChecked'}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

I updated the code to make more sense and to get rid of unnecessary instance methods. I would highly suggest that you get rid of the `state` in your `ChildCheckBoxCell` and try to feed it down via `props` as part of your `cell` object in my first example.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! I have just tried implementing it and for some reason, the `CheckboxCell` does not respond to the changes made in the listView. In step 1 i have `cell.isChecked = !cell.isChecked`, but the component and does not respond to these changes. Also, `componentWillReceiveProps()` does not get called in the `CheckBoxCell`.

Comment: When you update the data source you have to use cloneWithRows. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: The missing link is that I am not updating the datasource, I will try that now, thanks

Comment: That worked, once I realized I needed to re-create the datasource based on the changes, thanks again!